# Sherlock and the beast - Hackerrank

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, greedy

I have written this code in javascript for [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast) hackerrank challenge:

```
function main() {
    var t = parseInt(readLine());
    for(var a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        var n = parseInt(readLine());
        if(n < 3) {
            process.stdout.write("-1\n");
        } else if(n % 5 == 0 && n % 3 != 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                process.stdout.write("3");
            }
            process.stdout.write("\n");
        } else if(n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 != 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                process.stdout.write("5");
            }
            process.stdout.write("\n");
        } else if(n % 5 != 0 && n % 3 != 0) {
            var nts = 5;
            n -= 5;
            while(n % 3 != 0) {
                n -= 5;
                nts += 5;
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                process.stdout.write("5");
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < nts; i++) {
                process.stdout.write("3");
            }
            process.stdout.write("\n");
       } else if(n % 15 == 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                process.stdout.write("5");
            }
            process.stdout.write("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

It passes the test cases 0, 1, 2, 4, 5 and 10 but not the others. What am I doing wrong? Dont tell the correct solution. Just a hint would work I think. :P

Comment: You are thinking about it in a very complicated way. Hard to say what hint would help, except think it from the beginning again and find the general case. It's very simple.

Comment: How would i know to think it in another way? ._.

Comment: Your approach is fine. Single-step through your code with _N_ = 6 and you'll soon spot the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints, If you don't want a working solution, don't look at the code below :) 
1. if N is less than 3 there cannot be a decent number
2. The more 5's the bigger the number, since we want the biggest number possible, we will check to see how many 5's we can fit it before looking at 3's
3. if N is a multiple of 3 , then the biggest number possible would be all 5's
4. if N is not a multiple of 3, see how many 5's can fit in and leave enough space for some 3's
Eg. N = 19 ... remember the number of 3's can only be multiples of 5 (0 or 5 or 10 or 15... so on) 

        **First Try - would say 18 5's and 1 3('s) - this is not valid**

        Therefore reduce number of 5's by 3 and try again 
        **Second try - 15 5's and 4 3's - invalid still** 

        Therefore reduce number of 5's by 3 and try again 
        **Third try - 12 5's and 7 3's - invalid still** 

        Therefore reduce number of 5's by 3 and try again 
        **4th try - 9 5's and 10 3's - VALID!!**

Hope it helps somewhat

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            if(n<3){
                printNumber(0,0);
            }
            else if(n%3==0){
                printNumber(n,0);                
            }
            else {
                int rem = n%3;
                int k = 5;
                boolean divides = false;
                while(k<=n){
                    divides = (k-rem)%3==0;
                    if(divides){
                        break;
                    }
                    k+=5;
                }
                if(divides){
                    printNumber(n-k,k);
                } else{
                    printNumber(0,0);
                }
            }            
        }
    }

    private static void printNumber(int fives, int threes) {
        if(fives== 0 && threes==0) {
            System.out.println("-1");
            return;                   
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(fives>0){
            sb.append("5");fives--;
        }
        while(threes>0){
            sb.append("3");threes--;
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: See your first else condition for instance - you check if n is multiple of 5 but not a multiple of 3 and then you print all 3's... So is n is 20 ... Your answer is 3 repeated 20 times... Whereas the biggest number would have 5 repeated 15 times followed by 3 repeated 5 times..... So basically you need to examine your logic... I've mentioned the logic I used in my post